# Find subviews within rectangle

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, subview

I have a large `UIView` with many small `subviews`. I need to find all `subviews` within an area. I am currently iterating through `subviews` and using `CGRectContainsPoint`. This works, but 90% of the subviews are usually not within my rectangle of interest.

Is there a more efficient way to find all `subviews` within a rectangle?

Thanks

Comment: :you need to count your subviews?

Answer (score 2):

`CGRectContainsRect` would be more appropriate. You'd still need to loop through all subviews that might be in your rect based on what you can assume about their positions, but `CGRectContainsRect` still makes more sense than `CGRectContainsPoint`.

```
CGRect area = CGRectMake(10,10,200,200);
NSMutableArray *viewsWithinArea = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (UIView *aView in [self.view subviews]) {
   if(CGRectContainsRect(area,aView.frame)) [views addObject:aView];
}
```

Comment: Do you know of any way to filter the subviews easily? Was hoping there was an easy way to quickly eliminate views that are very far away.

Comment: Four lines of code is pretty easy. Any method Apple would provide would also have code behind it so just wrap up what I gave you in a method.

Comment: well, if a subview isn't isn't contained, its subviews won't be contained either.

Answer (score 0):

**@james_womack**'s answer in **Swift**:

```
func subviewsWithin(area: CGRect) -> [UIView] {
    return subviews.filter { area.contains($0.frame) }
}
```