# How to find all subviews in a particular frame size?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I want to find all subviews which are inside of a particular frame size.

I have my custom `UITableViewCell`, in that cell I am attaching various `UIImageViews` as subviews of `UITableViewCell` content view, and I added `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` in each cell.

My action method of `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` looks like this:

```
- (void)handleLongPressGestureRecgonizer:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    if(sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
        self.startPoint = CGPointMake([sender locationInView:sender.view].x,
                             [sender locationInView:sender.view].y);

    }
    if(sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        self.endPoint = CGPointMake([sender locationInView:sender.view].x,
                           [sender locationInView:sender.view].y);
        CGRect frame = CGRectMake(self.startPoint.x, self.bounds.origin.y, self.endPoint-self.startPoint, self.bounds.size.height);

    }
 }
```

Now I want to find out what are the `UIImageView` located inside the frame that I found in action method of `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`.

But I am thinking that I have to iterate all the cell contentView subview and check if that frame intersects with my identified frame or not.

Either my approach is correct or there is any other easy way to achieve this, kindly help me.

Thank you...

Comment: tag your image views, according to tag you will find, what object is tapped

Comment: i am not using tab gesture in my image view. i added long press gesture in my each cell, which i mentioned in my question. i want to find out all the image view which lies inside of that frame.

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7671114/find-subviews-within-rectangle

Comment: @Mihai pop, i know this way so i mentioned in my question it self for iterating all the subview, but, still my question is any other alternative and easy way is there to achieve this functionality or this is the best way. Any way thank for the ans...

Comment: As far as I know that's the solution: to loop through the subviews. The touch event is not passed to the subviews if the "current" view handles the touch. So I guess you have to loop though all subviews and check if the frames intersect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find out what views are in a specified section of a common superview then you do need to do some iteration and a 'hit detection'. Using the frame intersection as you say is good.

Rather than iterating all subviews, which would need to be recursive, you should maintain a property which is an array of all of the image views such that you can iterate that array directly and ignore any other subviews that aren't interesting.

Comment: instead of using one more array to store all the image view information, i can use cell.contentview.subviews to get all the subview of the cell right. becz, i am not adding any other view in my cell. but my cell style is default, so according to `UITableViewCell` type default, provide its own label, image etc right.

Comment: You can run a test to see what subviews are in the content view (and you can think about removing them when you add your subviews)

Answer (score 0):

you can use clean code with objective c run time like this:
in header file declare:

```
extern const char* MyConstantKey;
```

@interface .....yourInterface

and in .m you can define like this:
//private stuffs goes here
const char* MyConstantKey = "MyConstantKey";

then some thing like this:

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPress:)];
objc_setAssociatedObject(longPress,
                             (void*)MyConstantKey,
                             yourArrayOfImageViews,
                             OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);
```

and you can can associated object like this:

```
- (void)longPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)gesture
{
    NSArray *arrayOfImages = objc_getAssociatedObject(gesture, (void*)MyConstantKey);
}
```

Comment: And the aim of this is?

Comment: hi mr.Alok, u got my question?.

Comment: @Wain sorry i got your question wrong, basically question was more on regarding getting views only containing in long press area, rather than how to pass array :(

Answer (score 0):

You should set tag for UIImageViews which are subview of UITableViewCell

You can get indexPath of row :

```
-(void)handleLongPressGestureRecgonizer:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)sender{  
  CGPoint p = [sender locationInView:self.moTableView];
  NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.moTableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:p];
  //get your cell, get all images in your cell
 }
```